# login and logout by webdriver.Remote()

Tags: python, authentication, webdriver, appium, logout

I'm using appium to run my android test but each time it runs my app logout and again login. I think it's occurs because of this part of my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(appiumURL, DesiredCapabilities)
```

Do you have any idea to solve it? I want to login just for one time and after that my app be login for ever.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your capabilities, check [reset strategies](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/)

In short, adding `noReset: true` on Android will keep your app cache saved and with new Appium session there will be no need to log in again.